# Stop multiple PIDs

Tags: linux, pid

help me how to kill multiple pids. Its running more than 200 PIDs & difficult to kill one by one by using
`kill -9 Pid`

```
xyz 30146     1  0 20:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30272     1  0 21:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30399     1  0 19:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30557     1  0 21:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30613     1  0 21:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30668     1  0 19:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
xyz 30716     1  0 20:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/expect -f /home/xyz/monitors/bin/cm_remote_data cm_ps_data_ex_v2 abc NA NA -f /opt/xyz /monitors/sys/kim.pid
``
`

Any help, how to kill them in single go ?
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50573

Comment: tried, dint worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
pkill -f /usr/bin/expect
```

Use `-9` only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ps -ef |  awk '$NF ~ /your_process_name/ && $NF !~ /awk/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

You can search for several programs at the same time, you can also replace the pattern with variable.

```
ps -ef |  awk '$NF ~ /your_process_name1|your_process_name1/ && $NF !~ /awk/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```